# How to reach my Springboot docker container's endpoints from an Springboot api running on the local machine's localhost?

Tags: docker-compose, localhost, host, spring-webclient

I have 2 microservices, one is a **registration API** using a Postgres database, and the second microservice is a **login API**. I used `docker compose up --build` to generate the registration miscroservice docker image, which also generated 2 bound containers, `airport_registration_container` for the springboot registration api and `postgres_container` for the postgres database run together from the docker-compose.yml file. I added **EXPOSE 1993** to the Dockerfile of the registration API to publish its port outside of the docker. `The second microservice` which is login api is not a docker container, but I want to perform `unit testing` of the login methods using Jupiter.

> The login API's unit tests require to get registered users from the
> airport_registration_container endpoints running in its docker container.

I’m using spring webClient of springWebflux to get the registered users and I'm having issues with the HOST specified in the webClient's URI parameter. I tried 4 differents HOST and each is giving different error message as follow:

**1. First HOST** : localhost

When I use localhost in the webClient'uri parameter like
public UserDto retreiveUserById(){

```
    return webClient.get().uri("http://localhost:1993/users/admin", id)
    .retrieve()
    .bodyToMono(UserDto.class)
    .collectList()
    .block();
}
```

I receive the *403 Forbidden* from GET http://localhost:1993/user/admin/02ed840f-6a5d-4b8e-8b05-896c96148309:

"-- Error response code is **403 FORBIDDEN** and response body is
15:47:17.745 [main] ERROR com.emuragroup.agculogin.restClients.UserRestClient -- WebClientResponseException in retrieving UserById
org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException$Forbidden: 403 Forbidden from GET http://localhost:1993/user/admin/02ed840f-6a5d-4b8e-8b05-896c96148309
at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException.create(WebClientResponseException.java:312)
Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException:
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
*__checkpoint ⇢ 403 FORBIDDEN from GET http://localhost:1993/user/admin/02ed840f-6a5d-4b8e-8b05-896c96148309 [DefaultWebClient]"

**2. Second HOST** : airport_registration_container

As the localhost is forbiden I mapped the localhost to the container name like `127.0.0.1 airport_registration_container` in /etc/hosts file and then changed the webClient URI to `"http://airport_registration_container:1993/users/admin"`

Here I received *Host is not specified* error as bellow:

"-- Exception in retrieving UserById
org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientRequestException: **Host is not specified
at** org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction.lambda$wrapException$9(ExchangeFunctions.java:136)
Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException:
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
*__checkpoint ⇢ Request to GET http://airport_registration_container:1993/user/admin/02ed840f-6a5d-4b8e-8b05-896c96148309 [DefaultWebClient]"

**3. Third HOST :** docker container IP adress 172.21.0.3

It appeared to me that the login microservice in my local machine was unable to reach the registration API from docker. So I did

> “docker inspect \   -f
> '{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}'
> airport_registration_container  “

to get the registration's IP address which gives 172.21.0.3, and I then changed the webClient's URI to “http://172.21.0.3:1993/user/admin”

Here I received *connection timed out: /172.21.0.3:1993* error as bellow:

"-- Exception in retrieving UserById
org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientRequestException: **connection timed out: /172.21.0.3:1993
at** org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction.lambda$wrapException$9(ExchangeFunctions.java:136)
Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException:
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
*__checkpoint ⇢ Request to GET http://172.21.0.3:1993/user/admin/02ed840f-6a5d-4b8e-8b05-896c96148309 [DefaultWebClient]"

**4. Fourth HOST :** host.docker.internal

I tried to find the reasons of the time out error, and it seems to me that the 172.21.0.3 address is reachable but not responding to the login api call due to docker itself blocking the request. So I continued my researchs, and from [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach) I found that `host.docker.internal` is the substitute for localhost to reach a docker container, and I added this

```
extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    command: sleep infinity
```

to the docker-compose.yml. Now in doing this I received *Failed to resolve 'host.docker.internal'* error as bellow:

"-- Exception in retrieving UserById
org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientRequestException: **Failed to resolve 'host.docker.internal' [A(1), AAAA(28)] after 6 queries
at** org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction.lambda$wrapException$9(ExchangeFunctions.java:136)
Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException:
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
*__checkpoint ⇢ Request to GET http://host.docker.internal:1993/user/admin/02ed840f-6a5d-4b8e-8b05-896c96148309 [DefaultWebClient]"

As you can notice in that stackoverflow post the requests was made from the docker container to the local machine, and the fact that my situation is in inverse order is possibly the reason why it didn't work for me ?
And so pursuing my researchs in [this documentation](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/networking/#there-is-no-docker0-bridge-on-macos%23i-want-to-connect-from-a-container-to-a-service-on-the-host), I want to know what it means when they say `I want to connect from a container to a service on the host` or `I want to connect to a container from the host` ? Which host are they talking about ? What is `docker host` and what is `docker localhost` ?

Ultimately my question is, How to reach my Springboot docker container's endpoints from an Springboot api running on the local machine's localhost ? I'm really out of inspiration and out of solutions. I highly appreciate your help.

> System:

- OS: Mac Big Sur 11.6.1
- Docker Version: 24.0.2

Answer (score 1):

In your docker-compose file, do you have a port mapping line, mapping `airport_registration_container` container's `1993` port to the host's `1993` port? Something like below:

```yaml
ports:
  - 1993:1993
```

With such a mapping, a non-docker app running on localhost would be able to access an app running on docker at `localhost:1993`.

I was able to test and verify the connectivity, by connecting a demo app, which I ran on the localhost without docker using `./gradlew bootrun`, to one of my spring boot apps which I ran using docker-compose.

**docker-compose.yml file for app 1:**

```yaml
version: '3.5'
services:
  email-sender:
    image: devatherock/email-sender:latest
    environment:
      EMAILSENDER_SMTP_EMBEDDED: 'true'
    ports:
     - 8081:8080
```

The container's `8080` port is mapped to localhost's `8081` port, so my demo app running on localhost outside docker should be able to access this app at `localhost:8081`.

**Controller of app 2:**

```java
package io.github.devatherock.controller;

import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

@RestController
public class HelloController {
    private final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public Map<String, Object> sayHello() {
        return restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8081/actuator/health", Map.class);
    }
}
```

When I run the second app on localhost using `./gradlew bootrun` command and hit the controller endpoint at `http://localhost:8080/hello`, it successfully connects to the health check endpoint of the first app running within docker at `http://localhost:8081/actuator/health` and returns the result. You can find the complete demo app, along with the `docker-compose.yml` file on [github](https://github.com/devatherock/spring-boot-demo/tree/connect-to-docker-app)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions I tried all that without success and it appeared to be a network and system issue. So I'm trying to set up a proper dev environment with virtual machine and I'm still hitting the same "timeout wall" for docker registry as I posted in this new  question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77855453/i-cant-login-into-my-private-registry-from-the-host-machines-command-line. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

In newest version of docker desktop, i had the similar problem, I changed "localhost" to "docker.for.mac.localhost" worked for me, if you are in windows then it will be "docker.for.windows.localhost"

Comment: I receive the same error as for host.docker.internal : Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: Failed to resolve 'docker.for.mac.localhost' [A(1)] after 6 queries.