# I can't login into my private registry from the host machine's command line

Tags: virtualbox, minikube, docker-registry, client-certificates, .htpasswd

This is a couple of weeks since I’m having nightmares failing to login into my private docker registry inside minikube virtual machine on macOS Big Sur with vitualbox 6.1.48 as hypervisor. The registry:2 based container itself is up and running as you can on this screenshot for a docker ps command
[image]

From the screen you can see that my private registry is available on the `0.0.0.0:5000`, which means that I can access it from another docker container on 0.0.0.0:5000, and from my macOS's command I should be able to access it on `localhost:5000`.
When I type the command: `docker login 0.0.0.0:5000`, I receive this error

> « INFO[0018] Error logging in to endpoint, trying next endpoint
> error="Get "https://0.0.0.0:5000/v2/": net/http: TLS handshake
> timeout »

I also try to login with localhost:5000 and I receive the same error message as the error above TLS handshake.

So I type the command: `minikube ip` and receive `192.168.59.108` which is my minikube virtual machine’s ip adrress. Then I try to login with that address: `docker login 192.168.59.108:5000`, but this time I receive the error

> error="login attempt to https://192.168.59.108:5000/v2/ failed with
> status: 401 Unauthorized"

You can see all the error messages as on the below image:
[image]

In debugging the issue I get the logs of the container by: `docker logs 04d865955936`, and I receive the result you see on the screenshot below.It shows no error but is telling of http.secret and I don’t know where that file is located:
[image]

In fact I used self signed certificate from `mkcert` to secure the communications with the registry and the volumes where the certificate `.cert` and `.key` file are stored are well shown when SSHing in the container.The `htpasswd` authentication file for managing users is also in there.
This is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  basic-auth:
    restart: always
    image: registry:2
    container_name: kernel-registry
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    environment:
      REGISTRY_STORAGE_FILESYSTEM_ROOTDIRECTORY: /data
      REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE: /certs/registry.crt
      REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY: /certs/registry.key
      REGISTRY_AUTH: htpasswd
      REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_REALM: basic-realm
      REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_PATH: /auth/htpasswd
    volumes:
      - /data/:/data
      - /certs:/certs
      - /auth/:/auth
```

When I remove the TLS certificate and key from the docker-compose environnement configuration, I receive message saying http: `server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client.` which means that the certificate is mandatory and should not be removed.

I went trough almost all the similar issues of logging into private registry with self signed certificate but nothing is really identical to my case. I disabled my antivirus, I Typed on the console export `no_proxy=localhost,127.0.0.1,192.168.59.108:5000,192.168.59.109:5000,0.0.0.0:5000`, I Deleted and recreated the VM, but all that not to avail. Some people tell of configuring `~/.docker/daemon.json` or `/etc/sysconfig/docker` but no such file exit on my system.
So actually I’m totally confused not even knowing what is the source of these error and where to debug it from. It's now like a huge pain in the ass and I really need your help to solve it. Thank in advance for any help.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: From the virtualbox tag: **Notice: Only programming-related questions are on-topic**

Comment: In addition to making this question accessible to those that cannot "read" the pictures, this question needs a lot more focus. It contains a stream of conscious debugging session and is bouncing between not understanding IP routing, confusing authorization issues with TLS encryption, and adding a list of filenames you want help with. Please focus on a single [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like it is mentioned in a comment, it is not clear from the question what you originally set out to do - setup a local registry with auth, setup a local registry with auth + TLS, setup a local registry with auth and TLS with self signed certs or something else. If it is a local registry with auth and TLS with self signed certs, I don't think it can be done at least as per a note on [the docs](https://distribution.github.io/distribution/about/insecure/). If it is just a local registry with auth, I was able to achieve that with the below `docker-compose` file:

```yaml
version: '3.7'

services:
  htpasswd:
    image: httpd:2
    command: >
      sh -c "
        htpasswd -Bbc /auth/htpasswd testuser testpwd
        chmod 644 /auth/htpasswd
      "  
    volumes:
      - ./auth:/auth

  registry:
    image: registry:2
    depends_on:
      - htpasswd
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    environment:
      REGISTRY_AUTH: htpasswd
      REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_REALM: Registry Realm
      REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_PATH: /auth/htpasswd
    volumes:
      - ./auth:/auth
```

The username and password will be `testuser` and `testpwd` respectively. The first service creates the htpasswd file at `./auth/htpasswd`, that the second service, which is the registry, then uses. Once the registry is up, I'm able to login with a command like below:

```
echo "testpwd" | docker login localhost:5000 -u testuser --password-stdin
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it and received the same error message "Error response from daemon: login attempt to http://localhost:5000/v2/ failed with status: 401 Unauthorized". I'm on MacOS 12.1 Montgomery without docker desktop, but with minikube's docker engine.

Comment: Yeah my need is to setup a local registry with auth and TLS with self signed certs. Is this impossible ? The link you shared rather said that it's possible and that it is better than setting a registry with only htpasswd. If you find a link explaining how this can't be achieved, please let me know. Ultimately I'm grateful for your attention.

Comment: I think that was my bad - I missed a command that I executed manually to update file permissions. I have added that also to the docker-compose file now. Can you check if it works?

Comment: Whit the update I logged in successfully, but this is without TLS encryption and thus I can't deploy the images to a remote server. At least the authorization issue is now  solved, and I will apply the permission you gave to the certs files also and see if I can also get the certificates validated. Thank you very much.